# Why I cannot have the default value when null is allowed in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a list of 10 places that I put them as values in my SQL reporter 2012.
In my report I am counting the number of clients based on the selected place.
What I want is to have the total of clients in all places in case no value was selected by default.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your query/datasource to account for when the `null` value is selected by user.

In your `available values` you need to put an entry for `Null` values as Value and `All Places` as Label. when the user selects the All places (internally Null) you can pass that into your query.

Your where clause would look something like this:

```
Where ...
AND (Place = @Place Or @Place is Null)
```